# Google Sheets - Include a Comparison Trend Line

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts-trendlines

I am using google sheets to record sales data and have a separate worksheet for each calendar year.

For each calendar year I include a couple of charts which illustrate things like track dollar value of sales per week and I've included a trendline.

Now we've ticked over to a new calendar year, I'd like to include the trendline from last year's dollar value chart into this year's chart, so I can see how the trends compare.

I don't really want to include the week by week data in the chart (it will look messy & I don't need that level of detail) - is there a way I can just include the trend line?

Comment: Please mark the question as solved so others can benefit as well.

Comment: @marikamitsos - have done ... I was hoping for some alternative approaches too but none forthcoming!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have 'solved' this by pulling in the previous year's data, including the trend line in the series & then setting the colour for the series to none. That way the trendline appears but the individual data points don't.

I suspect this is the right way to do this but I'd be interested to hear of any other approaches.

Comment: This is great. Still. Could you please also include a sample sheet with dummy data and results _(read only or comment only)_? It would help others to maybe come up with alternative solutions as your expressed interest.